# Problem in response.write escaping quotes

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Hey friends please help me ...
how can i write `response.write` statement..... i want to put radio button but threre is some problem in `response.write` to get string from the record set `RS` and `ORS`...

```
set ORS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
getopt="SELECT * FROM Options WHERE QuestionID=" & RS("QuestionID")
ORS.Open getopt,Conn

if not ORS.EOF then
    ORS.movefirst
    do
        response.write " <input type='radio' name=' 'Question' & RS('QuestionID')& ''' value='Answer' & ORS('OptionID') & ''' > <h2 >" & ORS("Option") & "</h2><br />"
        ORS.movenext
    loop until ORS.EOF
end if

RS.movenext
loop until RS.EOF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes `"` to delimit server side strings, and single quotes `'` for the client side:

```
response.write " <input type='radio' name='Question" & RS("QuestionID") & "' value='Answer" & ORS("OptionID") & "'> <h2>" & ORS("Option") & "</h2><br />"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's better to break long string into smaller, more manageable chunks. Try --

```
response.write "<input type='radio' name='Question"
response.write RS("QuestionID") & "' value='Answer"
response.write ORS("OptionID") & "'> "
response.write "<h2>" & ORS("Option") & "</h2><br />"
```